# Does A* pop node in incremental cost order (like Dijkstra's) from fringe for consistent heuristics?

Tags: algorithm, heuristics

A heuristic is **admissible** if it never overestimates the true cost to reach the goal node from  n.

If a heuristic is **consistent**, then the heuristic value of n is never greater than the cost of its successor.

For admissible heuristic a later popped node can update the cost of target node although it might have some result already, that is way we need to run the algorithm as long as no other node in fringe has less value then currently found cost. Is this case different for consistent heuristic?

Comment: Your definition of consistent is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A consistent heuristic also satisfies h(x) ≤ d(x, y) + h(y) for every edge (x, y) of the graph, where d is the edge distance.

When a heuristic is consistent the first time a node is expanded in A<sup>*</sup>, we have found the optimal path to that node. Each node will be expanded exactly once, in the order of cost.